# Boost traits to check if an object is STL container

Tags: c++, boost, stl, type-traits

I am refactoring a serialization library in my project so that it compiles with 
`-std=c++11` and want to identify if an object is a STL container, e.g.

```
is_stl_deque<T>::value
is_stl_list<T>::value 
is_stl_vector<T>::value
is_set<T>::value
is_map<T>::value
is_pair<T>::value
is_sequence<T>::value
```

**Is there any boost trait to check if an object is a STL container ?**

If not (I couldn't find any), how can I implement one ?

Comment: You're probably solving the wrong problem. First off, "STL container" is poorly defined, secondly, you miss a few Standard Library containers, and thirdly, what about containers that are "STL-like"? Qt containers for instance.

Comment: You could use [is_same](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same), or the [boost equivalent](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_same.html)

Comment: If you're already using Boost, why not use [Boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg In fact I'm refactoring existing serialization library so that it compiles with -std=c++11 and migration to Boost serialization might break backward compatibility of my existing data.

Comment: Okay then, how about making a trait-class to check if there are `begin` and `end` methods defined for the target class? That would work with all standard containers, as well as the Qt containers, and maybe from other libraries as well. It can be done, and has been done (just search a little, and you will find links to such questions right here on SO).

Comment: Since when is `std::pair` a container?

Comment: Or you can make a generic template class, and use class-specialization for e.g. sequences (classes which can be iterated, using e.g. `begin`/`end`), pairs, tuples, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if there's anything in boost, but the things in your list are easily implementable with partial specialization:

```
template<class T>
struct is_vector : std::false_type { };

template<class T, class Alloc>
struct is_vector<std::vector<T, Alloc>> : std::true_type { };
```