# Unifying container traits

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, type-traits

I want to build traits that will answer questions like `is_vector`, `is_list` etc. The problem is I have to make two versions of each, namely the template template parameter one :

```
template<template<class,class> class C>
struct is_vector1 : std::false_type { };

template<>
struct is_vector1<std::vector> : std::true_type { };
```

and the simple template arguments one :

```
template<class T>
struct is_vector2 : std::false_type { };

template<class T, class Alloc>
struct is_vector2<std::vector<T, Alloc>> : std::true_type { };
```

and each would be used in different contexts

```
// 1
is_vector1<std::list>::value; 

// 2
template<typename C>
auto func(C const& data) -> typename std::enable_if<is_vector2<C>::value>::type
{ /**/ }
```

Is there a way to have only one version usable in both contexts ?

### Note

I don't have the option of making the base template, a variadic template one, I'm working in pre C++11 contexts

Comment: Would the alternate function definition syntax with trailing return types not be invalid in a pre-C++11 context?

Comment: @gha.st 1. It's there just to give an example 2. I believe [it is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25420508/2567683)

Comment: @gha.st Yep, correct. Bad copy paste , thnx for spotting, I corrected it

Comment: Happens to the best of us ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it by overloading function templates:

```
template<template<class, class> class T>
typename enable_if<!is_vector1<T>::value, char>::type is_vectorf();

template<template<class, class> class T>
typename enable_if<is_vector1<T>::value, char(&)[2]>::type is_vectorf();

template<typename T>
typename enable_if<!is_vector2<T>::value, char>::type is_vectorf();

template<typename T>
typename enable_if<is_vector2<T>::value, char(&)[2]>::type is_vectorf();
```

After that, just add a simple macro that uses `sizeof` to translate the return type of the function:

```
#define is_vector(T) ::std::integral_constant<bool, sizeof(is_vectorf<T>()) != 1>
```

Usage is fairly obvious, but might require a `typename` if it results in a dependent name. You can see [an example here](https://ideone.com/XICkvV).

Note that `::std::enable_if`, `::std::integral_constant` and `::std::declval` are all from the C++11 standard library, but it is fairly easy to emulate them with C++03.

Comment: So give a common interface that utilizes SFINAE under the hood. Nice !